# User @Value springboot annotation as enum value

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, spring-annotations

```
Given:
application.yml --> content

kafka:
  topicA: topic-a
  topicB: topic-b


public enum KafkaTopicBeanMapping {
    TOPICA(@Value("${kafka.topicA}", "ratelimiterABean"));
    TOPICB(@Value("${kafka.topicB}", "ratelimiterBBean"));

    private final String topicName;
    private final String ratelimiterBeanName;
}
```

But in the above case, I am getting error that `@Value("${kafka.topicA}")` cannot be used here.
I don't want to put ratelimiterBeanName as part of application.yml.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Java Enums are static in nature, they can be initialized only once. @Value in Spring makes values dynamic in nature which enums are not capable of.